# Need Command line for label difference

Tags: clearcase

I would like to display the content changed between two labels for a file specified.

I did this using find command of `cleartool` earlier, but this was a two way process:

- First determine the elements changed between two labels using the `-version` switch in find
- and then pass the two versions for a file in the `diff` serial switch to display the output.

What I need now is to have the same done using a single command wherein I will specify the filename and the two labels.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the branch in which the labels have been applied, you can use the [extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904), following the rule of [version selector](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/version_selector.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-6-12&lang=en):
(See [about the version-extended path](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/about_version_path.htm?lang=en))

```
cleartool diff myFile@@/main/myBranch/MY_LABEL1 myFile@@/main/myBranch/MY_LABEL2
```

---

if you don't know their full extended pathname, you need first a find, in any view (snapshot or dynamic), which visualize the file (at whatever version).

```
cleartool find myFile -ver "lbtype(MY_LABEL1)
  File@@/main/myBranch/MY_LABEL1

cleartool find myFile -ver "lbtype(MY_LABEL2)
  File@@/main/myBranch/MY_LABEL2
```

Once you have the full extended pathnames, you can use the `cleartool diff`.

Comment: I may not know the branch ,all that I have is the file name and the two labels.
Basically a script is needed to first detemine the extensionpath info and then pass the same into the diff.

Comment: @Raj: I have extended my answer to address the lack of extended pathname.