# Get specific version of unloaded file with cleartool

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

So I'm writing a script at work where I have to go through all the projects in a ClearCase vob, look for a file and parse some info from said file.
Naturally, I wouldn't want to load every single project so I'm using cleartool to retrieve the unloaded files.
First, I'm using the find command to locate the files. This was my first attempt:

```
root>cleartool find C:/viewpath -name file.txt -version "lbtype(Version-label)" -print -nr
```

Viewpath is the path to the project where I'm currently looking for the file. The file I'm looking for is `file.txt` on the version specified by Version-label.
This gave me no result whatsoever, even though I knew `file.txt` existed on that version.
I figured out it was looking through an old version of the directory, the latest on the main-branch, which was before `file.txt` was added to the directory. I tried this instead:

```
root>cleartool find C:/viewpath@@/Version-label -name file.txt -version "lbtype(Version-label)" -print -nr
```

And got this result, which was what I was looking for

```
C:/viewpath\file.txt@@\main\branch\41
```

So now that I knew where I could find the file I tried to get it.

```
root>cleartool get -to savepath C:/viewpath\file.txt@@\main\branch\41
```

Which gave me this result

```
cleartool: Error: "C:/viewpath\file.txt@@\main\branch\41" does not exist, or is not a ClearCase version, or is a checked out version which was removed.
```

Also tried

```
root>cleartool get -to savepath C:/viewpath\file.txt@@/Version-label
```

With the same result

I can get files added to the directory when it was still on the main-branch, so it is still searching through the directory on the main-branch, where `file.txt` is nowhere to be found.
How do I tell it to look through a version of the directory from after it was branched from main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really recommend for you to try those same commands in a dynamic view.
As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904), a dynamic view gives you access to **extended path** (the `file@@/branch/version` syntax), which means command like `get` will work.
You have in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437260/need-command-line-for-label-difference/3437635#3437635) an example of search (`cleartool find`) using extended paths.

As explained in "[In ClearCase, how can I view old version of a file in a static view, from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176858/in-clearcase-how-can-i-view-old-version-of-a-file-in-a-static-view-from-the-com/177350#177350)", you can browse (as in 'change directory to') the various extended paths of a file in a dynamic view.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378 on dynamic views.

Comment: I'm merely a summer worker here and unfortunately don't have a say in whether dynamic or static views should be used. Is there no way to accomplish this with a static view?

Comment: @Nait: Yes, through ct diff, as my last link illustrates (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176858/in-clearcase-how-can-i-view-old-version-of-a-file-in-a-static-view-from-the-com/177350#177350). But dynamic views are made precisely to get access to and explorer *all* version (and you perfectly can a snapshot and a dynamic view with the same configuration).