# ClearCase UCM: Need to See Content of Deleted File

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Using Clearcase UCM and ClearCase Explorer, I some time ago deleted a file (command-line equivalent would be rmname). I now need to see the content of this file, but of course it is not shown as being in the directory. How may I get at the file's content (i.e. how do  Ilook at the previous directory version--the version that existed before the delete)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow a process similar to the IBM technote "[Restore an element that has been rmnamed](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21149206)", which will allow you to find back the right version.

If you know the file name, you can search for its most recent version with:

```
cleartool find . -name "filename" -nvisible -print
```

If you are searching in a dynamic view, you should get a result like:

```
M:\view\vob\directory@@\main\4\<missing-element-name>
```

This is an **[extended path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904)**, which you can directly access in a dynamic view:

```
type M:\view\vob\directory@@\main\4\<missing-element-name>
```

See also "[Get specific version of unloaded file with cleartool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204929/get-specific-version-of-unloaded-file-with-cleartool/7205294#7205294)"

Comment: Note: if your file was unreferenced and put in "`lost+found`", see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21120317