# Cleartool - find unloaded/removed files

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Is there a command in Cleartool which i can use to list all files which have been removed from a branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic command to find anything in ClearCase is... [`cleartool find`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm?lang=en), also illustrated in "[ClearCase UCM: Need to See Content of Deleted File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934086/clearcase-ucm-need-to-see-content-of-deleted-file)".

In your case, you would search for versions of files which aren't at the LATEST of a branch:

```
cleartool find . -type f -version "! version(.../BRANCH/LATEST)" -print
```

(see [version selector](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/version_selector.htm?lang=en) for more on this '`.../`' notation)

To display only the file (and not *all* the versions):

```
cleartool find . -type f -element "! version(.../BRANCH/LATEST)" -print
```

---

The [OP linuxlewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24481/linuxlewis) mentions in the comments:

> this will show all differences which exist between sibling branches. I just want to be able see the file names,if any were removed,from the current branch

I mention the possibility of a `grep` for `BRANCH`, to detect files which have versions in `BRANCH` but not `LATEST`)

However, a cleaner solution is to add another filter to the search: `&& version(.../BRANCH)`

```
cleartool find . -type f -element "! version(.../BRANCH/LATEST) && version(.../BRANCH)" -print
```

That will search all "elements" (files or directories in ClearCase) which have versions in branch `BRANCH`, but not one in `BRANCH/LATEST`.

Comment: ok but this will show all differences which exist between sibling branches. I just want to be able see the file names,if any were removed,from the current branch

Comment: @linuxlewis you can grep for `BRANCH` (if it has version in `BRANCH` but not `LATEST`), it is a file for you. Or you can add a '`&& version(.../BRANCH)` which should select all elements with versions in `BRANCH` without a version in `BRANCH/LATEST`.

Comment: The ... wildcard link is now stale. Use this instead (for CC 8.0.1): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/wildcards_ccase.htm

Comment: @GergelyPolonkai thank you, I have updated the other links as well.

Comment: @VonC: Hi, i've tried the cmd "cleartool find . -type f -element "! version(.../BRANCH/LATEST) && version(.../BRANCH)" –print" but I only get the error message:  cleartool: Error: Extra arguments: "-print". Did the command syntax change?

Comment: @airborne Sorry, I left some minus in the answer, instead of hyphen-minus: https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309. If you copy-pasted and then changed the command, you need to change the '`-`' from `–print` to `-print`: '`–`' is not the same as '`-`'...

Comment: @VonC: Sorry to bother you again. "cleartool find . -type f -element "version(.../mybranch/LATEST)" -print" works for me, but "cleartool find . -type f -element "version(.../mybranch)" throws an "cleartool: Error: Malformed branch pathname: "\..."." Any idea what I'm still doing wrong?

Comment: @airborne Check this thread: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013792593&ps=100&tags=&query=&filter= : you might need to add a version in there, like LATEST: `.../mybranch/LATEST`