# ClearTool: Finding changes from specific date

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I am at loss on how to

1. list all files and directores that were *deleted* from branch "xyz" on
   date Mar-1.
2. List all *directories* that had their contents changed on that same day.

I tried transcribe the patterns from [Cleartool - find unloaded/removed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695833/cleartool-find-unloaded-removed-files) from branches to dates, with no success.

Thanks a million

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The find commands I mentioned in "[Cleartool - find unloaded/removed files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11696443/6309)" are for files only.

You can use them for directory if you use `-type d` (instead of `-type f`)

But that wouldn't address the date issue.

since a file deletion results in a new *directory* version (to record that deletion), I would search for all *directory* versions created on that day:

```
cleartool find . -type d -version 'created_since(01-Mar) && !created_since(02-Mar)' -print
```

Then, I would compare with previous versions (`cleartool diff -previous`) for each of those directory version found, in order to grep and list the deleted files.

Comment: Awesome reply! In speed as well as precision. I had only to insert a blank after the "!" to keep Linux from chewing it into something different!