# rename element in clearcase with @@ in filename

Tags: clearcase

For some reason some users produced some files that end in "`@@`" (...) (I think because they have in the CCRC the gui option to show the version extended pathname and i think that has somewhere a little bug).

Now... they are unable to remove or rename these files (it returns "not a object in the vob")

how can they rename or remove these files?

**update**

Resolved I forgot to use the complete rmname "a.doc@@@@\bla\1", after the full path i could delete them.

Comment: Excellent. I have updated my answer to reflect your cleartool command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to try to list and remove those objects from a base ClearCase view directly on the CCRC server (or any base ClearCase client).

From this kind of ClearCase installation (CCRC server or full ClearCase client), you do have access to cleartool (the ClearCase CLI -- Command Line Interface --), and you can:

- `cleartool ls`: list the files in the view, to check those files with `@@` are indeed there
- `cleartool rmane -force` to remove them

The OP used

```
 cleartool rmname "a.doc@@@@\bla\1"
```

, meaning he had to use the **[extended path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904)** (file name + `@@` + version path) of the file ended with `@@`, hence the four `@`: `file@@@@version`.

Comment: Unfortunately even in base clearcase view then running "ct rmname -force bla.doc@@" gives "not an VOB object ... hmmmm....

Comment: @edelwater: I have already seen those kind of objects (with `@@` at the end) as representing **cache** objects (i.e. not versioned by ClearCase, only used internally by ClearCase). Could you edit your question with the exact output of a `ct ls` from the parent directory?

Comment: @edelwater: if the "cache" is confirmed, the first think to try is to close completely the view (`ct endview -server view_tag`) and go into it again to see if the file is still there. If it is, the second try is a reboot ;)

Comment: Sorry VonC, I did not give the complete path to rmname, after that I could delete them.