# What is the nature of a "MVFS filesystem" with ClearCase?

Tags: unix, filesystems, clearcase

What does MVFS in a clearcase server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVFS (Multi-Version Filesystem) don't so much "create" a filesystem, but give you access to one.

`M:` (on Windows) or `/view` (on Unix) is a mounting point allowing to browse the content of any Vob (the ClearCase repositories) you mount (like a classic network mount, but made by ClearCase).

When you create a dynamic view, you will use MVFS to browse the "dynamic" filesystem, meaning you want load any file on your hard disk: you will remotely see any version you have selected through the config spec of the view.

See [About the MultiVersion File System (MVFS)](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21230196):

> The MultiVersion File System (MVFS) creates a virtual file system specifically designed for accessing data within a Rational ClearCase VOB.
>
> The MVFS works similarly to UNIX® Network File System (NFS), in that it loads a kernel driver that presents a file system to the user through a standard interface within the Windows, UNIX or Linux kernel.

Notes:

- a snapshot view won't use MVFS (see "[What are the differences between a snapshot view and a dynamic view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378)")
- With a dynamic view, you can directly browse any version you want, using **[extended pathnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904)**.
- Any read/write operation is done through cleartool and ClearCase: you cannot, as you tried in your previous question "[rm doesn't detect failure of fchdir in walkfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662006/rm-doesnt-detect-failure-of-fchdir-in-walkfs)", to rm elements through a Unix `rm` or Windows `del`. Only cleartool command can modify an element managed by ClearCase in a dynamic view.