# What does the * mean when listing views in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

On executing command

```
ct lsview | grep -i <some_string>
```

The result is a list of views.
Few of them are something like

```
* <view_name1>
```

What does this star (`*`) mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means they are dynamic views (MVFS Multi Version filesystem) [which are started](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_start_dynamic_view.htm).

When you start a view, it becomes visible in `/view` (unix) or `M:\` (Windows), the MVFS mounting point.
See "[What is the nature of a “MVFS filesystem” with ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677751/6309)"

This would not apply to snapshot views, as they are always available directly in your local disk: see "[What are the differences between a snapshot view and a dynamic view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309)"