# ClearCase: are element names view dependent?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I am running the cleartool subcommand `diffbl -versions` between two baselines. But the output looks different depending on the view I am running the command from. The difference is in the path name of the elements. For example the same file `my_filemane` located in `/vobs/my_component/my_directory/my_subdirectory/` as seen by two views on two streams `my_stream_1` and `my_stream_2` shows path names:

```
/vobs/my_component/my_directory/my_subdirectory/my_filename@@/main/my_stream_1/1
/vobs/my_component/my_directory/my_subdirectory@@main/my_stream_2/my_stream_1/10/my_filename/main/my_stream_1/1
```

In the fist case its easy to determine the location of the file, is there was no version control, by taking the substring between `/vobs/` and `@@`. Is there any easy way (a cleartool subcommand maybe) to find the same from the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference comes from the visibility of the file within the view from which you are doing the `diffbl`.

Considering the **[extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904)** from the second path mentions:

```
 main/my_stream_2/my_stream_1/10
```

, your best move is to redo said `diffbl` from a view associated with stream1 in order to get a simpler path for that particular file.
But anyway, since that file has no version in stream2, it will always be displayed with a long and complicated extended pathname.