# clearcase latest version of a file on a particular branch

Tags: clearcase

I know the filename of a clearcase versioned file. How can i find the latest version of this file on a particular branch ? It should not pick any child branches. Also the parent branch names may not be know always.

Thanks.

Comment: I have added the `cleartool find` option, which should be what you are looking for, especially if you don't always know the parent branches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a dynamic view, you can directly access the `LATEST` version of a given branch by using the **[extended path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904)**:

```
cat file@@/main/branch/subbranch/LATEST
```

If you don't know the exact branch path (parent branches) this version is stored in, you can modify your dynamic view and add first the selection rule

```
element /path/to/file .../subbranch/LATEST
```

That will select the `LATEST` version of subbranch within the dynamic view.

Or **you can do a `cleartool find`, in order to see the full extended path for that file**:

```
cleartool find . -name "yourFile" -ver "version(.../subbranch/LATEST)
```

You will be able to `cat` (or `type` in Windows) directly the result (which will be the *full* extended path)

The diea behind the `cat` or the `cleartool find` is to be able to use the syntax `.../subbranch/LATEST`.
That syntax with the three dots means: '`.../subbranch`' whatever branches followed by `/subbranch`.

Comment: I am setting the view, as you suggest, and then using the "cleartool ls" to find file version. Thanks for the reply