# Clearcase: moving a sub branch to a main branch

Tags: clearcase

In clearcase I started work on a branch called `main/release4/release5`. After I had began my work, release4 was merged into main. My coworkers started work on main/release5. Is there anyway I can move my `main/release4/release5` work to `main/release5`?

So far, I've tried to merge from `main/release4/release5` to `main/release5` but that didn't work. The files stayed on `main/release4/release5`.

Visual example of what it looks like in version tree:

```
main
|   \
|     release 4
|     /      \ 
main        release 5
    \              \
    release 5      *move files from here
         \ 
         *to here
```

Here is the original config spec I was working with.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element - directory * /main/LATEST
element * /main/release4/release5/LATEST
element * /main/release4/LATEST -mkbranch release5
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch release4
```

Here is the config spec my coworkers started with after merging release 4 with mainline

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element - directory * /main/LATEST
element * main/release5/LATEST
element * main/LATEST -mkbranch release5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of those selection rules ending with `branchname/LATEST -mkbranch newBranch` is to allow an *element* (file or directory) to start a new branch from whatever version happens to be the LATEST, unless there are already versions on said `newbranch`.

So it is a file-by-file mechanism.

To ensure all files to start from the release4 merged into main, put a label on *all* elemenents of `main/LATEST` right after that merge (preferably using the *snapshot* view used for said merge), then use a config spec like:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../release5/LATEST
element * REL4 -mkbranch release5
element * main/LATEST -mkbranch release5
```

Starting a branch from a *fixed* label is safer than starting from `/main/LATEST` (which can see a new version at any time)

---

The OP [Gregory Peck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1408045/gregory-peck) comments:

> using `.../release5/LATEST` fixed it!

The reason the "three dots" syntax worked (as illustrated in "[clearcase latest version of a file on a particular branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140611/clearcase-latest-version-of-a-file-on-a-particular-branch/12140897#12140897)") is that some versions had their branches starting from the `release4` branch, other from `main`.

With `.../release5/LATEST`, you select the `LATEST` of `release5`, no matter which branch `release5` is starting from.

Comment: using `.../release5/LATEST` fixed it! Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @GregoryPeck Excellent. I have edited the answer to explain why this syntax is working.