# Clearcase How to grab the latest file when there is many child branches from parent branch?

Tags: clearcase

Usually I get the files from main branch where all the latest changes occur. But how should I get the latest file when there is many sub branches from parent branch and changes occur in all the branches but I needed to grab the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

You can focus on one branch:

```
element * .../aBranch/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST
```

You can focus on several, but you have to chose the one you will consider first:

```
element * .../aBranch1/LATEST
element * .../aBranch2/LATEST
element * .../aBranch3/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST
```

The order of the selection rules matters: if there is a version in `Branch1`, it will be selected. If not, the next selection rule applies.

In all cases, note the '`.../`' notation, which allows you to select the latest version of a branch, for any branch path (`/main/Branch1`, or `/main/Branch2/Branch1` or ...)
This is what allows you to select the LATEST of a branch, even if that branch derives from many other branches.

See also (for other examples of the three dots syntax):

- "[clearcase latest version of a file on a particular branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12140897/6309)"
- "[Clearcase: moving a sub branch to a main branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12714528/6309)"