# What clearcase command I should use to to get who checked in last?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I am new to ClearCase, and I need to get who check-in a particular file last (ie: latest version).

I know the absolute path for the file.
What command do you recommend for me to access the user (ie the creator of the LATEST version) for that file?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cleartool descr -l /path/to/file
```

If your view already select the latest version, that is enough.

You can also use **[`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)** to isolate only the information you need:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%u" /path/to/file
```

If you view doesn't select the `LATEST` version (which you can check by doing a `cleartool ls` in the parent directory, and looking at the selection rule displayed there), you can use the extended path name to deduce its LATEST path:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%u" /path/to/file@@/main/branch/subBranch/LATEST
```

See more at "[clearcase latest version of a file on a particular branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140611/clearcase-latest-version-of-a-file-on-a-particular-branch/12140897#12140897)", in order to *find* the exact extended path you want.