# ClearCase merge not updating LATEST in a local branch

Tags: merge, branch, clearcase

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12140611). Basically, I checked out a file in my local branch and, later, I performed a merge from the main branch, which already had a newer version of this file. I find it weird that file@@/main/branch/subbranch/LATEST still contains the older version of the file, from before performing the checkout. Shouldn't the merge operation also update this link?

For merging, I used this command:

```
cleartool findmerge /my_file_folder -nc -fver .../branch -merge
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`cleartool findmerge`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm) will checkout and merge, but won't check in.

As long as you do not checkin, the extended path `@@/main/branch/subbranch/LATEST` won't reflect the result of that merge.