# clearcase query results into winmerge

Tags: clearcase, winmerge

I can compare two files in Winmerge by triggering a comparison on the command line with a command similar to:

```
WinMergeU C:\file1.txt C:\file2.txt
```

I can query a list of files with particular properties in clearcase with a clearcase query similar to:

```
Y:\VOB_A>cleartool find . -type l -exec "cleartool describe -fmt "%n %[slink_text]Tp\n\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""

.\Directory\createsymlink.txt -->..\..\VOB_B\SymlinkFolder\createsymlink.txt
```

What I want is to generate a set of clearcase query results that can then be used as input to winmerge (ie generate a bunch of diff commands on checkins fulfilling a certain criteria like user or day).

**How can I write a clearcase query to get a list of file elements (referable in clearcase ie winmerge could open the path to the version on a dynamic view), and get their corresponding previous version of the file?**

The bit to format this to winmerge I imagine would look somewhat like this:

```
... describe -fmt "WinMergeU ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One, you would need to generate the right [full extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904) for each file (one being the result of your query, one being the previous version of the one found by said query)

Two, you need to do so in a dynamic view (in order to access to any version though the extended path name of the file.

Once your query gives you a version, you can ask, with a `cleartool descr -fmt "%PSn"` (see [`fmt_ccase` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)), for the previous version and add that to your result file.

Trying to do it all in one pass (find + predecessor version + WinMerge call) seems too complicated.

Comment: Thanks VonC - you're a wealth of Clearcase information. I also really enjoyed your preso on Git in the enterprise. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "seems too complicated?"

Comment: @hawkeye trying to -exec or pipe one output to the other is error prone. I prefer dumping the result of one command in a text file, making sure its content is correct, then process that content to the next command.