# Including check-in date when finding my ClearCase check ins?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I'm using the code:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\cleartool.exe" find . -name "*" -ver "created_by(someuser)" -print > c:\my_checkins.txt
```

to find a list of my check-ins in ClearCase.  I'd like to include the date of the check-in.  Can I do that?  If so, how?  Can I have the results sorted by the check-in date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an -exec directive to describe and format the result of each version you are finding with your `cleartool find` query.

Instead of using -print, you can combine a find with a formatted describe (Windows syntax):

```
 cleartool.exe" find . -name "*" -ver "created_by(someuser)" -exec "cleartool descr -fmt \"%n - %d\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

`%CLEARCASE_XPN%` being the [extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904) of one of the versions found by the query.

See the [`fmt_ccase` page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm).

You might want to use the format "`%Nd - %n\n`" if you want to sort by date, because is `%Nd` is a date expressed as `yyyymmdd.time`.