# What could cause cleartool.exe to crash when being executed using CMD batch script?

Tags: triggers, runtime-error, cleartool

I have a batch script that calls `cleartool` to execute the `lsactivity` command after being triggered by a `checkin` operation.  Results from the call are written to an output file.  The line in my batch is:

```
cleartool lsactivity -long "%ACTIVITY%">streaminfo_%timestamp%.txt
```

where `%timestamp%` is a variable that contains the date and time, making each call unique.

98% of the time I have no problems.  The remaining 2%, however, is when cleartool crashes leaving a locked 0KB file that causes the CMD script to hang until closed using Sysinternals Process Explorer.

After browsing through the OS (Win 2003 Server) system event viewer, I found [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndmge.png) that corresponds to the timestamp given to the blocked file, and is classified as Information and not Error:

```
Application popup: Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library : Runtime Error!

Program C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\bin\cleartool.exe

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
```

Has anybody else encountered this issue before or have any suggestions to solve or as to why it happens?

[This thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14529023) on an IBM forum is about the same issue, but it has not been answered.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Your cc projects aren't linked to Clearcquest, are they? (as in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21321509)

Comment: @VonC Yes, it is linked to ClearQuest.  The problem in the link is not the same as what I am experiencing, but I'll take a look.

Comment: Are you using the CC version same as server? Are you able to recreate the error running directly from command line? Is Jenkins running as a service? If so, is it running as admin with access to CC?

Comment: @EldadAK The CC versions are all compatible, yes.  I have not managed to recreate the error directly from command line, no, even though I tried.  I do not have Jenkins installed, no.

Answer (score 0):

Pending a definitive answer for the root cause of the cleartool crash (like this [cc-cq link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21321509)), I would set a Windows job which would:

- monitor for any 0kb file in the directory used by your trigger script to write its files
- kill the trigger process and relaunch it.

Comment: Would this be possible with dynamic variables?  The trigger creates directories and files based on the environment variables being set during execution of the trigger such as `%ACTIVITY%` and `%CLEARCASE_PN%`.  Even if I was able to monitor with a Windows job, how would I re-launch the trigger again and ensure that the same variables are passed?

Comment: @Andrew you would need to write down the parameter for each trigger instance (and delete that parameter file after the successful completion of the `cleartool` command). If that parameter file remains, it means `cleartool` has failed, and the job can read said file in order to launch again the same script with the same parameters.