# How do I label new files on a branch using cleartool?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

To provide some context, I am trying to write a script which will take a text file with clearcase elements in it, and label all of those elements.

To generate the text file, I am basically using the following command:

```
cleartool find -a -nxn -ele "brtype(branchName)" -print > "textfile.txt"
```

Then I go through the text file and remove the elements I don't want to label. The last step would be to feed the text file into a script which would repeatedly call a cleartool command on each line of the file.

For all existing files/folders, I can run this command:

```
cleartool mklabel -rep "label_name" (element_path)
```

Where I run into trouble is with files that have been added to the branch. They print out to the text file in a format that isn't recognized by the "mklabel" command and I can't find a good way to parse them.

The format of the files is similar to the following:

```
\original_folder_path@@\branch_name\version_number\new_sub_folder_path\branch_name\version_number\file_name.java
```

In the past I have used this generic command we use at my company to blindly label all files in a branch:

```
cleartool find -all -branch "brtype(<branch>)" -version "version(.../<branch>/LATEST) && !version(.../<branch>/0)" -visible -exec "cleartool mklabel -rep <label_name> %CLEARCASE_XPN%"
```

But I only want to label about half the files on the branch I am using, and there are too many to label them individually. I am sure I am missing something obvious here. Does anyone know how I should change my find or mklabel command to accommodate the new files and folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That format "\original_folder_path@@\branch_name\version_number" is an **[extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309)**, and isn't reserved for "added file".

It is current rather for files listed by a [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm?resultof=%22find%22%20), but not visible (directly accessible) in the view used by the `cleartool find`.

You need to make sure to use a view which is set to select the LATEST from brname.

If you see extended pathnames in your `cleartool find`, you can ignore them: they are not accessible by said view.

Or you could use a `cleartool find -cview`, in order to limit the results to what you view is able to select and see.

Comment: I tried the find command in my main snapshot view, and like you said, the extended pathname files appeared in the normal format. The funny thing is I was using a view with the same config spec when I was seeing the extended pathnames. The only difference was the original view was a dynamic view. Guess that makes a difference. Thanks for the help. I would upvote but don't have enough rep.

Comment: @RyanA.Latham the two views should yield the same "find" result, if their config spec (in term of selection rules, the "`element * xxx` rules) are identical.