# Cleartool findmerge error

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I'm running this command :

cd into view directory 
cd into the relevant folder

```
cleartool findmerge rvnDataPathEgressProcessor.cpp@@\main\RavenAppMain_Integ\RavenApp1.5\RavenApp1.5.0.0_Integ\RavenApp1.6.0.0_Integ_OBS\RavenApp1.5.2.0_Integ\RavenApp1.5.5.0_Integ\14 -fversion rvnDataPathEgressProcessor.cpp@@\main\RavenAppMain_Integ\RavenApp1.5\RavenApp1.5.0.0_Integ\RavenApp1.6.0.0_Integ_OBS\RavenApp1.5.2.0_Integ\RavenApp1.5.5.0_Integ\aviv.sharon_RavenApp1.5.5.0\15 -print -whynot
```

I'm getting this error:

`cleartool: Warning: A version selector is required, not a pathname:`

```
"rvnDataPathEgressProcessor.cpp@@\main\RavenAppMain_In
teg\RavenApp1.5\RavenApp1.5.0.0_Integ\RavenApp1.6.0.0_Integ_OBS\RavenApp1.5.2.0_Integ\RavenApp1.5.5.0_Integ\aviv.sharon_Ra
venApp1.5.5.0\15".

No merge "rvnDataPathEgressProcessor.cpp" [no version "rvnDataPathEgressProcessor.cpp@@\main\RavenAppMain_Integ\RavenApp1.
5\RavenApp1.5.0.0_Integ\RavenApp1.6.0.0_Integ_OBS\RavenApp1.5.2.0_Integ\RavenApp1.5.5.0_Integ\aviv.sharon_RavenApp1.5.5.0\
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`cleartool findmerge`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm) requires `pname`:

> One or more file, directory versions, or both; only the specified file versions and the subtrees under the specified directory versions are considered.

If `rvnDataPathEgressProcessor.cpp@@\main\RavenAppMain_Integ\RavenApp1.5\RavenApp1.5.0.0_Integ\RavenApp1.6.0.0_Integ_OBS\RavenApp1.5.2.0_Integ\RavenApp1.5.5.0_Integ\aviv.sharon_RavenApp1.5.5.0` is *not* an existing **[extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309)**, there is no version to be found, and that would explain the error message.

Try finding a view which already select the destination version, and do a:

```
cleartool descr -l rvnDataPathEgressProcessor.cpp
```

That would give you the exact and full extended pathname.

The OP [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573451/cleartool-findmerge-error/26573593?noredirect=1#comment41765921_26573593) the second argument should be the version only, without the file:

> `\main\RavenAppMain_Integ\RavenApp1.5\RavenApp1.5.0.0_Integ\RavenApp1.6.0.0_Inte‌​g_OBS\RavenApp1.5.2.0_Integ\RavenApp1.5.5.0_Integ\aviv.sharon_RavenApp1.5.5.0\15` *without* the `rvnDataPathEgressProcessor.cpp@@`.

Comment: This is the version that i got:
`version "rvnDataPathEgressProcessor.cpp@@\main\RavenAppMain_Integ\RavenApp1.5\RavenApp1.5.0.0_Integ\RavenApp1.6.0.0_Integ_OBS\RavenApp1.5.2.0_Integ\RavenApp1.5.5.0_Integ\aviv.sharon_RavenApp1.5.5.0\15"`
`aviv.sharon_RavenApp1.5.5.0` is a stream and i've used the `cleartool describe -l` command in this view, but the `findmerge` command i'm using in the `RavenApp1.5.5.0_Integ` view in the parent directory.
Any idea what should be the 2nd parameter of the `findmerge` command?

Comment: I thing that i've solved it, the 2nd parameter should include just the version and not the path, so the 2nd param will be:
`\main\RavenAppMain_Integ\RavenApp1.5\RavenApp1.5.0.0_Integ\RavenApp1.6.0.0_Integ_OBS\RavenApp1.5.2.0_Integ\RavenApp1.5.5.0_Integ\aviv.sharon_RavenApp1.5.5.0\15`
Without the `rvnDataPathEgressProcessor.cpp@@`

Comment: @user3502786 That could work indeed. That would be consistent with the output of the command, which only mentions versions. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @user3502786 no, I never used it for a single file. I generally used it on a folder (in your case, the parent folder), because the file itself can be moved, renamed or deleted from one version of the parent folder to the other.