# full clearcase history for gource

Tags: clearcase, gource

I have tried to get the full history of a **clearcase vob** to parse it and use it with **gource** to get a visual representation of the changes, but I do not find the right commands to get an easy log history to parse with [clearcase2gource](https://github.com/p3t3c/clearcase2gource) python script. I do not use UCM, there are no streams, just plain cleacase.

With this command I get elements with @@ in the middle of a path:

```
cleartool lshistory -fmt "Element: %n| Date: %d| User:%u| Operation: %e| Object:%[type]p| SimpleType: %m| OperationKind: %o\n" -all /vobs/vob_name
```

With this command I get elements like this (deleted at some point):

```
Element: /vobs/vob_name/dir1@@/main/branch_dev/2/dir2/main/branch_pilot/1/file@@/main/branch_pilot/1| Date: 2008-04-15T16:58:28+02:00| User:reeasjp| Operation: create version| Object:compressed_file| SimpleType: version| OperationKind: checkin
```

That makes more difficult to parse for gource because of several branch names in the middle.

Is there any way to get a full history of all the elements with just plain directories and file names?

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: In the config Spec I have just "/main/LATEST".

Answer (score 0):

The issues are:

- [`clearcase2gource.py`](https://github.com/p3t3c/clearcase2gource/blob/cb6be37425c6cd27502a313f2eeeb615785808b2/clearcase2gource.py#L45-L51) processed the [extended paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309) (see "[About the version-extended path](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/about_version_path.htm?lang=en)") found by `cleartool lshistory` with some hard-coded assumptions.

```py
    e = d['Element']
    splitElement = e.split("@@")
    d['FileName'] = splitElement[0]
    d['StreamName'] = splitElement[1]
    # StreamName starts with /main/ which we aren't interested in.
    # Remove the /main/ (slice on 5 because there are 5 chars in /main/)
    d['StreamName'] = d['StreamName'][5:]
```

- the `cleartool lshistory --all` will list history of deleted elements (non-visible anymore in the current ClearCase view), hence the multiple branch names.

The easiest solution would be to:

- redirect the `cleartool lshistory` output to a file, and
- then filter out all the extended paths which don't conform to `clearcase2gource.py` expectation: for instance, just for testing, keep only the ones in a specific branch or in `/main` only, just to see if that works better.
- finally feed that file as input to `clearcase2gource.py`

Comment: Nice summary, thank you. Your solution proposed is my plan B, but I was looking for a `cleartool` commands (maybe a mix between `find` and `lshistory`) to have a pretty print history of all the elements current and past with its changes.