# How to get the logs in XML file in cleartool. I want the output of command cleartool lshistory in XML file

Tags: java, logging, clearcase, cleartool

I am trying command **cleartool lshistory > file.txt** through this I am getting the file in text format similarly I want the log file in XML format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`cleartool lshistory`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-25) doesn't offer xml output.

You would need to parse its output, and generate the expected xml yourself.

[akshay jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015386/akshay-jain) asks [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913554/how-to-get-the-logs-in-xml-file-in-cleartool-i-want-the-output-of-command-cleart/30917284#comment49878173_30917284):

> how we can get the logs in well formatted way so I can parse it easily and store the values in db?

[Using `fmt_ccase`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), you can control exactly the ouput you want, for better parsing (as [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29297980/6309)):

```
cleartool lshistory -fmt "Element: %n| Date: %d| User:%u| Operation: %e| Object:%[type]p| SimpleType: %m| OperationKind: %o\n" -all /vobs/vob_name
```

The OP adds:

> I want the version changes logs only not other logs, is there any way?

I mentions %c (comment message), but:

> Is there a way to handle the `%c` output, because it is disturbing the format of log file?

I then mention %Nc, which avoid appending newlines at the end of the comment message.

The OP [confirms in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80992/discussion-between-akshay-jain-and-vonc):

> `%Nc` works thanks

Comment: how we can get the logs in well formatted way so i can parse it easily and store the values in db

Comment: @akshayjain I have amended the answer to address your comment/question.

Comment: hi von i want the version changes logs only not other logs is there any way

Comment: @akshayjain sure, look at the `fmt_ccase` man page I mention. `%n` should give you the version. What do you mean by "version changes log"? The checkin comment message? That would be `%c`.

Comment: is there a way to handle the %c output because it is disturbing the format of log file

Comment: @akshayjain Can you try `%Nc`? (avoid appending a newline after the comment)

Comment: version changes means i want only the checkin logs in the log file at every checkin version/revision changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80992/discussion-between-akshay-jain-and-vonc).

Comment: @akshayjain Great, `%Nc` works for you. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.