# List all ClearCase users that touched every version of an element

Tags: clearcase

I need to get a list of user names for every version listed in the version tree of an element, and then repeat for every element in the directory.

So far, I have come up with the following:

```
> cd M:\path\to\folder
> cleartool find . -version "created_since(01-January-1979.00:00:00)" -exec "cleartool describe -fmt ""%Lu\t%Fu\t%n\n"" %CLEARCASE_XPN%"
```

I chose a really old date thinking our VOB is younger than that date.

This gives me the same information for every version of an element because it's looking at the element owner, not the individual that contributed a specific version.

I'm using the following pages for reference:

- http://www.ipnom.com/ClearCase-Commands/describe.html
- http://www.ipnom.com/ClearCase-Commands/fmt_ccase.html
- http://www.ipnom.com/ClearCase-Commands/find.html
- http://www.ipnom.com/ClearCase-Commands/query_language.html

This might be a simple case of RTFM. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `%n` (used in the [`-fmt_case` directive](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-6-6&lang=en)) returns the element name of the version name:

- if it is the element name (without any **[extended path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309)** information, as in `@@/main/.../x`), then it would be normal for the [`cleartool describe`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-9) to return always the same information.
- if it is the extended path, as I would expect with `%CLEARCASE_XPN%`, then %u should be the user associated with the event (the version), and not the "element owner)

  ```
  %u
  ```

> Login name of the user associated with the event.

Small note, I always prefer using double-quotes around `%CLEARCASE_XPN%`, in case the path filename has a space in it.

```
-exec "cleartool describe -fmt ""%Lu\t%Fu\t%n\n"" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon closer inspection, it looks like the command I posted above is sufficient. I saw a bunch of user names that were the same and thought they were all the same, but that's not true. I'm seeing different user names for different versions of the same element as I originally wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on a multisited VOB, do not forget that the owner of an object created on another site will be the VOB owner on your site. Therefore, if an object was created and modified only in a remote site, all of its tree and version would be owned by the VOB owner.
Of course, I assume you are in non preserving mode for identities for your replica synchronization (see the [Changing preservation mode](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/t_change_preservation_mode.htm?lang=fi) for mode infos). In most cases, you would not want replication  to preserve identities, because each site has its own set of users.