# Find all the Clearcase files that exeeds 100MB in a particular VOB

Tags: clearcase

How to search all archived file that exceeds 100MB in a particular BASE Clearcase VOB. In Unix file system, it is easy:

```
find . -type f -size +104857600c -exec ls -la {} \;
```

Would it be possible to search directly in the folder of the VOB in the file system without create a Clearcase view and modify the config spec?

If I have to create a Clearcase view, would it be possible to use the cleartool command find to search in the whole VOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21296399):

> At present there is no size option available with the `cleartool find` command.
>   The decision was made by Product Management to exclude the requested feature from future upgrades and releases due to the significant architectural changes required to implement the solution.

So creating a view remains mandatory.
And you can either directly use the ClearCase Explorer:

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21296399&aid=1]

Or use your regular Linux command in a dynamic view:

```
# find . -size +20480c -print
./vendor/Common/NT/work/toolset/make/cal.output
./vendor/Common/NT/work/toolset/make/paf.output
```

> would it be possible to use the cleartool command find to search in the whole VOB.

"The whole VOB" as in "all possible versions"... not really, unless you try and find files in the [extended pathnames of an MVFS dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904). I haven't tested that option so.